# Live Partial Table / column replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication

I want to know if there is a way to achieve the following with SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition?

I have `Table A`: on `Server 1` with say 10 columns.

```
Table A:
| col1 | col2 | col3 | coln | col10 |
```

on `Server 2`, I need a live copy of `Table A` in `Table B` on `Server 2`. However I only actually need 3 of the columns replicated, as that's all I use.

```
Table B:
| col1 | col3 | col10 |
```

I mentioned "live" above, By this I mean that when I insert a new value or update a new value in `Table A` that change will be propagated as soon as it can to `Table B`.

`Table B` is a read only table. And `Table A` gets data written to it. So A will be the publisher and B the subscriber.

How can I achieve this sort of setup?  In other words do I need to use some sort of replication? or can I achieve this with Always ON High Availability.

Comment: You could use a trigger - much simpler to set up and troubleshoot than replication. IMHO.

Comment: How reliable is the trigger approach? Say for example it cant access the server at that time, how would It deal with that?

Comment: How does transactional replication deal with that? You can make the trigger as robust as you want it to be. By default it will roll back the transaction if it can't access the server. But you could make it resilient to that by testing the server and if the test fails store the changed rows temporarily in a local table. If you can't rely on the other server being up, though, you might consider trading real-time for a slightly more resilient approach like log shipping (and just concede the fact that you'll have a copy of the whole database). You could combine these - a trigger into a separate

Comment: local database on the same server, and log ship *that* database. This way the trigger doesn't have to worry about another server being up...

Answer (score 5):

You could also solve this with a trigger that populates the copy of the table on insert/update/delete. It wasn't clear in the question that these tables are actually on different servers, and that the subscriber was unreliable. In that case you could simply log ship to the subscriber - you can get pretty close to real time here, though you will have to kick users out temporarily as you restore new logs. If log shipping the entire database is a concern, then you could instead use a trigger to populate another database on the same instance - which only has this table and the required columns populated - and then log ship *that* database to the other instance:

[image]

I have a blog post on making log shipping work much more like a set of readable secondaries:L

- [Readable Secondaries on a Budget](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/sql-performance/readable-secondaries-on-a-budget)

You can also look at these posts for an approach I've used to do something a lot like replication but with more control, less impact, and none of the troubleshooting nightmares:

- [Schema Switch-A-Roo](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/t-sql-tuesday-schema-switch-a-roo)
- [Schema Switch-A-Roo : Part 2](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/schema-switch-a-roo-part-2)

I also talk about some ways to provide read-only copies of the data for reporting at the end of this post:

- [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 1):

Transaction replication would be the solution I would choose for this.

More info about transaction replication can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx

To only choose the columns needed, you need to use a column filter:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151775.aspx

AlwaysOn availability groups would not work here, as their availability replicas contains one or more databases - but can not be used at table level.